# Issues with highlight.js and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, highlight.js

Here is the HTML, pretty straight forward:

```
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <pre>
            <code>
                function() {
                    console.log("test");
                }
            </code>
        </pre>
    </section>
</div>
```

And I tried some CSS, but it didn't change anything:

```
code {
    text-align: left;
}
pre {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

You can see how it looks like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vV48/1/). I want the code on the left, and what is up that giant padding between the top `<pre>` and `<code>`?
Thanks! 
**UPDATE:** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6vV48/2/) is a working version, although the HTML doesn't look too good. Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 11):

This is because of the `pre` tag. It takes the given content as preformatted. This means it shows the tabs and spaces the way they are used in your document. Remove the tabs and spaces in front of your JS code and it works fine.

```
<pre>
// code example goes here without any indentation
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks, Here's the update: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6vV48/2/). However, now the HTML looks pretty messy. Is this the only way?

Comment: Sorry, i have no ideas how to accomplish this. Maybe you should ask a new question about this?

Comment: wasted 2 hrs for this.